# How to display Modal component on page load?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap-modal

I'm making an HTML5 game page and wanted to have my login form be a modal when the user loads the page. I have set the state to true and tried moving the state to app.js but neither works

```
export default class Modal extends Component {
  state = { show: true };

  showModal = () => {
    this.setState({ show: true });
  };

  hideModal = () => {
    this.setState({ show: false });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="modal">
        <section className="modal-main">
          <Login username={this.props.username} email={this.props.email} password={this.props.password} />
          <button onClick={this.hideModal}>close</button>
        </section>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I have the modal imported into app.js but it still is not loading.

Comment: Can you show your Login component? But anyways, your Login component is not listening to `show` property.

Comment: You don't actually do anything with `this.state.show`? You should add a conditional statement, or better yet, hide the modal from the parent component. See: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-modal

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like:

```
render() {
    return (
        <div className="modal">
            <section className="modal-main">
                {this.state.show &&
                    <Login username={this.props.username} email={this.props.email} password={this.props.password} />
                }
                <button onClick={this.hideModal}>close</button>
            </section>
        </div>
    );
}
```